# How to achive Chart JS weather chart of 5 day / 3 hour forecast data

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to display the date and time on the x-axis and the temp on the y-axis for every 3 hours in an area chart. The chart I am trying to make
[enter link description here](https://prnt.sc/1qti0s3) . I am currently using ApexChart to display an Area Chart.
Is there any way to get and show the date data only in time and in 12hour format using ChartJS?

```js
 fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=fd3150a661c1ddc90d3aefdec0400de4').then(response =>


        response.json()

    ).then(response => {
        dates = response.list.map(list => {
            return list.dt_txt;
        });

        temps = response.list.map(list => {
            return list.main.temp;
        });


        var options = {
            series: [{
                name: 'Temp',
                data: temps,
            }],
            chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: 'area'
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            stroke: {
                curve: 'smooth'
            },

            xaxis: {
                type: 'time',
                // categories: ["2018-09-19T00:00:00.000Z", "2018-09-19T01:30:00.000Z", "2018-09-19T02:30:00.000Z", "2018-09-19T03:30:00.000Z"],
                categories: dates,
                labels: {
                    // format: 'hh:mmTT',
                },
                time: {
                    parser: 'MM/DD HH:mm',
                    tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm',
                    unit: 'hour',
                    unitStepSize: 3,
                    displayFormats: {
                        'time': 'MM/DD HH:mm'
                    }
                }
            },

        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();


    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');

        * {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }

        #chart {
            max-width: 760px;
            margin: 35px auto;
            opacity: 0.9;
        }

        #timeline-chart .apexcharts-toolbar {
            opacity: 1;
            border: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="border border-primary m-3">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-8" id="chart">
                <div id="timeline-chart"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`time` is not a valid display format. Check the docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats).

You want to use the display format `hour` (the unit you use).

```
displayFormats: {
    'hour': 'MM/DD hA'
}
```